# Finding the Collatz Sequences of a range of numbers

Tags: haskell, sequence

I'm new to Haskell, and I'm trying to do Project Euler problem 14. I'm not done with the program yet, but the part I have done isn't working. This piece of code is supposed to print out the lengths of the Collatz Sequences of the numbers between 2 and 100.

```
main = print $ collatzSeq [] [2..100]

collatzSeq xs (x:s) = collatzSeq (collatzLength x []):xs s

collatzLength x y
    | x < 2 = length (x:y)
    | even x = collatzLength (x / 2) (x / 2):y
    | otherwise = collatzLength (3 * x + 1) (3 * x + 1):y
```

I've tried to modify the code in  various ways, and I believe the issue lies in the collatzLength function. But from what I have learned so far about Haskell, this function should work, but it doesn't and I don't get what I'm missing. I just get a compiletime error.

Comment: Not working how? Compile error? Wrong answer?

Comment: `collatzSeq` have infinite recursion.

Comment: Sorry, I get a compile error.

Comment: "I got a compile error". Read it. We can't

Comment: I would recommend breaking the problem up into smaller subproblems. 1. Given a single number, compute its Collatz sequence. 2. Using the function created at step 1, compute the length of a single Collatz sequence. 3. Given a range of numbers, compute lengths of the Collatz sequence of each number in the range using the function defined at step 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, There are some mistakes from your code. They are common mistake of those who are new to Haskell. I list them as below:

> 1. Function application always be left-associativity and the highest precedence than all operators.

So, the code:

```
even x = collatzLength (x / 2) (x / 2):y
```

is equivalent to

```
even x = (collatzLength (x / 2) (x / 2)):y
```

It is obviously wrong, because the second argument of `collatzLength` is `[Int]`, not `Int`

> 2. (/) function or / operator cannot apply to `Int` type or `Num` class.

see [(/)](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-47-) is applied to data type which is an instance of `Fractional` only, but `Int` is not. In your code, the division only apply to even number, so it can use `quot` instead as:

```
even x = collatzLength (x `quot` 2) ((x `quot` 2):y)
```

> 3. Missing base case of recursive function.

As talex has mentioned in comment, the recursive function `collatzSeq` never end. Since it miss the base case to indicate how the function should end its computation. In your case, it is common the check the input list whether is empty or not as:

```
collatzSeq xs []    = xs
collatzSeq xs (x:s) = collatzSeq ((collatzLength x []):xs) s
```

Finally, it is better to provide the type signature for function to make the code clear and readable.

Put them all together, the correction look like:

```
collatzSeq::[Int]->[Int]->[Int]
collatzSeq xs []    = xs
collatzSeq xs (x:s) = collatzSeq ((collatzLength x []):xs) s

collatzLength::Int->[Int]->Int
collatzLength x y
    | x < 2 = length (x:y)
    | even x = collatzLength (x `quot` 2) ((x `quot` 2):y)
    | otherwise = collatzLength (3 * x + 1) ((3 * x + 1):y)
```